# PHP : Saving Values and Div to another page

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make every user choose the market field that he is interested in with a checkbox [show/hide]- div method with javascript but i don't know to save every user selected checkbox-div,  do i use cookies or save it to database and how i can do it  in php?

```
    // function for show/hide divs depend on select input
  <script>
    function showMe (box) {
        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
        var div = "none";
            for(var i=0; i<chboxs.length; i++) { 
                if(chboxs[i].checked){
                    div = "block";
                     break;
                }
            }
        document.getElementById(box).style.display = div;
    }
 </script>
```

// the form for selecting the shop field

```
<form action="chooseShop.php" method="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="Electrionics" Onclick="showMe('cssmenu_1')">Electrionics<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="Clothes" Onclick="showMe('cssmenu_2')">Clothes<br / >
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="perfums" Onclick="showMe('cssmenu_3')" >perfums<br / >

    <button><a href="index.php">Next</a></button><br /><br />  
</from>

// THE Main DIVs
<div id='cssmenu' >

        <ul>
           <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Much Me</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Profile </span></a></li>


           <li class='has-sub' id="cssmenu_1" style="display:none" ><a href='#'><span>Electrionics</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 4</span></a></li>
                 <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 5</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>



            <li class='has-sub' id="cssmenu_2" style="display:none"><a href='#'><span>Clothes</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 4</span></a></li>
                 <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 5</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>


            <li class='has-sub' id="cssmenu_3" style="display:none"><a href='#'><span>perfums</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'><span>Product 4</span></a></li>
                 <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 5</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>

    </div>
```

Comment: do u know a bit of PHP atleast?

Comment: yes i know php and javascript but am still fresh

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how long you want to store the information. PHP sessions are the shortest, they will last only the amount of time the user has their tab open.

Cookies have the next longest shelf life, they will be stored on the user's browser for a specified number of days that you can set.

Databases are for storing information long term use. If you want your user's to be able to permanently save their preferences, this is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for User experience and you don't have to store the values in a database somewhere, I'd use local storage.

Here is [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gqqjsL4/3/) select one or two boxes then click run so the inner page reloads, you'll see your selections are remembered after the reload.

```
    function showMe(box) {
        //get and loop through all the checkboxes
        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
        for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {

            if (chboxs[i].checked) {
                // if the box is checked, show group save the selection to local storage
                document.getElementById("cssmenu_"+i).style.display = "block";
                localStorage.setItem("hasGroup" + i, "yes");
            }
            else{
                //otherwise set each group in not visible and save state to local storage
                document.getElementById("cssmenu_"+i).style.display = "none";
                localStorage.setItem("hasGroup" + i , "no");
            }
        }
    }


window.onload=function(){
    //check for saved groups and display them if found
    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
        var div = "none";
        if (localStorage.getItem("hasGroup" + i ) == "yes") {
            div = "block";
            //re-check the box
            chboxs[i].checked = true;
        }
        document.getElementById('cssmenu_' + i).style.display = div;
    }
};
```

Comment: How about using PHP SESSIONS to save DIV values to the next page ?

Comment: Youu could use php sessions, keep in mind that php code is only run once, as the page is loaded. As such, if you want to use php, you'd have to write a separate php page that sets and reads session vars. Then write an ajax call that sends the checked boxes to that page so it can update the session and have the php page return the session values back to set up html page. I could help you with that if needed. Keep in mind also that with sessions, when the user closes their browser, the information is all lost. localstorage persists.

Comment: So what is the perfect method to do it , i feel like the way you talked about is going to be hard for me am still fresh if u can help me i would be thankful for you . 
all i need to make users choose from checkbox the market fields that interested in so this checked boxes is going to be the users field button (like youtube left menu).
1- first page to select the fields 
2- Second page is the index.php
[and for the second page (index.php) save the checkedbox-divs for every login for the user]

Comment: It would help if I had a better idea of what your trying to do. Is this your actual html? Can you walk me through what the user uses the page for?

Comment: checkbox = to Show/Hide divs.
want to save every user selected divs to the home page

Comment: in that case, the method above using localStorage should work just as you need.